# Constructor errors

Tags: c++, class

I have this class header

```
//header for class.
#ifndef Container_H
#define Container_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


const int DEFAULT=32;

class Container{
    public:
        Container(int maxCapacity = DEFAULT);
        ~Container();
        void insert(int item, int index);
        void erase(int index);
        int size()const;
    private:
        int sizeC;                
        int capacityC;           
        int * elements;            
};
void info();
#endif
```

and this source file

```
#include "container.h"


Container::Container(int maxCapacity = DEFAULT){
    int y;
}
void Container::insert(int item, int index){
    int x;
}
```

and when I compile this, I get the following error message

```
test.cpp:4: error: default argument given for parameter 1 of `Container::Container(int)'
container.h:12: error: after previous specification in `Container::Container(int)
```

what have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions with no arguments still need the parentheses:

```
Container::Container() {
    int y;
}
```

Based on your header, it looks like you just forgot the maxCapacity argument, and it should actually be:

```
Container::Container(int maxCapacity) {
    int y;
}
```

(If you're asking about the warning too, it's pretty self-evident -- you declared an `int x` but didn't do anything with it)

EDIT: Well now you've edited it to completely change the error. Now it's an error because you're specifying the default argument in both places; you're only supposed to specify it in the declaration. Leave it out in the actual implementation, like my second example above

Comment: yup i know that, just wondering why the constructer gets an error. And i saw my mistake and fixed it but im still getting an error

Answer (score 0):

`Container::Container{
    int y;
}` is syntactically incorrect.

**EDIT:**

Try this:

```
Container::Container(int maxCapacity) // default argument not to be mentioned in the definition
{
  int y;
}
```

Comment: sorry, i've fixed it, and its still giving me an error.
"test.cpp:4: error: default argument given for parameter 1 of `Container::Container(int)'
container.h:12: error: after previous specification in `Container::Container(int)'"

Answer (score 0):

Your Container constructor (in the source file) should be like this:

```
Container::Container(int maxCapacity){
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Container::Container{
    int y;
}
```

I'm not sure what this is intended to be. If you're trying to define your ctor, it should look something like:

```
Container::Container(int maxCapacity) // ....
```

Note that you want to include the default value in the declaration, but *not* in the definition.